# Delete all sub-directories except one

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose under the current directory, there are multiple sub-directories, and one is called A.

How to delete all sub-directories except A with Bash?

Answer (score 24):

Bash has extended globbing (first test, then remove the echo):

```
shopt -s extglob
echo rm -rf !(A)
```

Comment: (before I forget - you might disable CSH style history completion, in Bash3 there's a bug while ignoring !(. set +H

Comment: +1 Bash if full of surprises! Sometimes they are nice like this one.

Comment: Wauw very nice indeed! Works as expected.  With ```shopt | grep ext``` You can see if the plugin is enabled.

Answer (score 14):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name A -not -name "." -exec rm -ir {} \;
```

Answer (score 10):

What about:

```
mv A /tmp/
rm * -rf
mv /tmp/A .
```

This avoids some of the "scariness" of a typo in the other commands.

**Please be aware** to not be in the root (/) folder when running the rm * -rf command above.

Comment: +1 for doing the sane thing instead of hoping the tools are smart enough.  still, one night, when i was just learning Linux, i copied the kernel to /tmp before doing my first recompile.  it didn't succeed, but erased the old one, so i said 'no sweat, i have a copy' only to find that a midnight cron task had erased it with every file more than a week old in /tmp!  i had to recompile again and this time do it right, or no reboot for me!

Comment: best answer posted :)

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
find . -type d -not -name A -exec rm -ir {} \;
```

should do.

**edit**

It should really be

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -not -name A -exec rm -ir {} \;
```

to prevent `find` from recursing below A.

Comment: But, this would also remove any sub-directories below A like A/foo and A/bar, but would preserve A/A.

Comment: Cool! Questions and answert get migrated from SO to SF... but my edit above was lost...

Comment: It should be better to swap maxdepth and type arguments like this : find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name A -exec rm -ir {} \;

Answer (score 1):

i usually do this by working up an ls command that gets it right first.  i'm not at a unix machine, but something like:

ls -lda "[^A]"

Once you get it right, pipe it to a command

ls -lda "[^A]" | xargs rm -rf

Feel free to edit above if I've got my regular expression wrong...

Comment: You shouldn't parse ls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be more flexible but manual you can do:

```
ls > /tmp/foo
edit /tmp/foo as you like
xargs -a /tmp/foo rm -r
```

That way you can do general munging.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  Be careful with this sort of thing, though, it's so powerful that it can only be used for good or evil...

```
find * -type d | grep -v "^A" | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Actually -v already negates the values, so "^" is not required, it's -v name_to_keep

Answer (score 1):

Don't use find as some people have shown with -exec and rm without passing -print0 to find and -0 to xargs.  It will get confused on file names with spaces or newlines:

```
$ mkdir 'foo foo'
$ mkdir foo$'\n'foo 
$ find . -type d -exec rm -ir {} \;
rm: cannot remove directory `.'
rm: remove directory `./foo\nfoo'? y
find: `./foo\nfoo': No such file or directory
rm: remove directory `./foo foo'? y
find: `./foo foo': No such file or directory
```

Instead use find -print0 with xargs -0 , '-exec command {} +', or -delete if your find supports it.

Answer (score 1):

See also here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862388/delete-all-files-directories-except-two-specific-directories

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the earlier example of:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name A -not -name "." -exec rm -ir {} \;
```

you can also do:

```
find some/subdir -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -name A -exec rm -ir {} \;
```

to avoid having to `cd some/subdir` first.

Answer (score 0):

find ...ROOT_FOLDER.../* -type d | grep -v FOLDER_TO_KEEP | xargs rm -rf